# Parametric infinite series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been going trough some exercises regarding Cauchy's root test and D'Alembert's ratio test for infinite series. Let me just say that I am aware that they are equivalent, due to Stolz–Cesàro theorem. I had some parametric series on hand, and since you can't never go too much in detail with analysis of entities with parameters (at least I had regrets every time I didn't do it), I first started by first applying basic convergence test, that is, series $\sum{a_n}$ diverges if $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n \ne 0$. Then I would apply appropriate test, root or ratio test, depending on the series. It struck me that for each and every one case the series converged for the whole interval in which it could actually converge. That is, if the convergence test said the series diverges whenever a parameter, say $p$, is in the interval $I$, then the series was convergent exactly at the whole interval $I$ when one of the two other tests was applied.

I am wondering is why is this happening. Was I not firm with my analysis? In all examples the parameter $p$ was given as a positive real number, so is it possible that for the negative numbers of $p$ those series do still diverge somewhere within $I$? I will state some of the practice problems that were more interesting, and the solutions I've got for them. I hope that someone could tell me If what I have noticed was somewhat of a fact, or does it just come down to the fact that $p$ was always positive. Can I at least always expect that for positive $p$ both convergence and root/ratio test give the same results? If not, what are some counterexamples?

#### Example 1:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(\frac{p\cdot n}{n+1})^n,\ p \in (0,+\infty)$$
Series converges for $p \in (-1,1)$. For this case I did actually took $p \in \mathbb{R}$, because it was not as hard to go through all the cases as for the other ones. Here I used the root test. Also $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n = \frac{1}{e}\lim_{n\to+\infty}p^n$ and $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=p$.

#### Example 2:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{(p+\frac{1}n)^n}, p\in(0,+\infty)$$
Series converges for $p \in (1,+\infty)$. Also
$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{e}}\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\frac{1}{p})^n$ and $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{1}p$.

#### Example 3:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{p^n+1}, p \in (0,+\infty)$$
Series converges for $p\in(1,+\infty)$. Here I couldn't really systematically simplify the limits in question so I went on intuition, though with same conclusions as before:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n = \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &0, && p > 1 \\
    &\frac{1}2, && p = 1\\
    &1, && p < 1
  \end{aligned} \right. ,$$
which yields that the series diverges for $p \le 1$, and $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &\frac{1}p, && p > 1 \\
    &1, && p \le 1\\
  \end{aligned} \right. ,$$ which yields that series converges only for $p>1$.

#### Example 4:

##### The last one, I promise

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+p)\left (\frac{p+1}{p^2+1} \right )^n, p \in (-1,+\infty)$$
Here limits are:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n = \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &0, && \frac{p^2+1}{p+1} > 1
    &+\infty, \frac{p^2+1}{p+1} \le 1
  \end{aligned} \right. ,$$
so the series diverges for $p \in ((-\infty,-1)\cup[0,1]) \cap (-1,+\infty) = [0,1]$, and
$$L = \lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \frac{p+1}{p^2+1}.$$ Since series converges for $L < 1$, we get $p\in(-\infty,0)\cup(1,+\infty)$. Since it is given that $p>-1$, finally series converges for $p \in(-1,0)\cup(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: I thinks you have stumbled upon something called as [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)

Comment: Well I do not think so, as that has to do with the series of functions fn(x), while my question only has series with positive, nonincreasing terms @Tutankhamun

Comment: Look at Example 1 it can be seen as power series , that is a function of p, $\sum (\frac{n}{n+1})^n \cdot p^n$ restricted to a positive domain. Also the corollary of root test is [cauchy hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard,unknown%20until%20Hadamard%20rediscovered%20it.)

Comment: Alright, I see that it can be.  The thing is, functional series were not introduced in the material that I am using at the point when those exercises are presented. Though I can see that this can be related to the radius of convergence, when I think about it. But that still does not answer the questions presented in my OP. Can you maybe address those in an answer? @Tutankhamun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac 1{p + n}$, for $p > 0$. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$, making $\sum_n a_n$ potentially convergent for all $p$.

But of course, a comparison to the harmonic series shows that instead it diverges for all $p$.

Comment: That is such a simple example! And yet I failed to think of it. Thank you very much! It seems like I was indeed just lucky with the example problems!

Comment: You weren't all that lucky in your examples. The vast majority of algebraic formulas for $a_n(p)$ are going to lead to exactly the same condition holding: they will converge for all $p$ where $\lim_n a_n(p) = 0$, except possibly at the boundary. To come up with a counter-example, first you need to find a divergent series on the edge of convergence, so $a_n \to 0$. Then you need to involve $p$ in a way that moves along that edge instead of across it. My example is surely the easiest solution where the involvement of $p$ is not completely trivial (such as $a_n = \frac pn$ would be).

Comment: I see. I must say that this is a very helpful insight! Thank you very much again!